# Nested generator or iterator for python

Tags: python, string, text, generator, iterable

I have the next list:

```
texts = [['abcdD', 'asdfaD'], ['qerqD', 'asdfafdasD']]
```

I want to delete all character `D` from the right part of all strings.

For one list I can do it easily:

```
res1 = [el.strip('D') for el in texts[0]] # ['abcd', 'asdfa']
```

Now I'm trying the same for each text:

```
res2 = [el.strip('D') for text in texts for el in text]
```

But it returns ONE list (combine my two!):

```
['abcd', 'asdfa', 'qerq', 'asdfafdas']
```

When I need next:

```
[['abcd', 'asdfa'], ['qerq', 'asdfafdas']]
```

How to do it correct?

Comment: Almost, just switch the order. `[[el.strip('D') for el in text] for text in texts]`

Comment: You need to *nest* the list-comprehensions.

Comment: @COLDSPEED `rstrip('D')` would be more precise.

Comment: Indeed, so it would, based on Op's description of the problem.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ you again! :D You helped me several days ago! Your comment works perfectly! If you post your answer, I would accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you'll need to *nest* one of the loops.

```
x = [['abcdD', 'asdfaD'], ['qerqD', 'asdfafdasD']]
y = [[j.rstrip('D') for j in i] for i in x]

y
[['abcd', 'asdfa'], ['qerq', 'asdfafdas']]
```

Which is easy to understand if you convert the above to a nested loop -

```
y = []
for i in x:
    y.append([])
    for j in i:
        y[-1].append(j.rstrip('D'))

y
[['abcd', 'asdfa'], ['qerq', 'asdfafdas']]
```

What you decide to use is really a matter of style. The list comprehension is concise, but suffers from readability issues. The loop is generally very fast and readable.

Comment: Hi, COLDSPEED. I used your answer while Alfe's answer look more safety. What do you think about it? Don't know what to accept :)

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam Hmm, Alfe's answer is for python2, while this would work for any version. Secondly, if your data is only a list of lists (rather than an arbitrarily nested list) then this addresses your question more to the point than Alfe's does. It's up to you. As you can see, someone was sweet enough to downvote my answer, so not everyone would agree with me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this recursive approach for arbitrary deeply nested structures:

```
def f(s):
  return [q.strip('D') if isinstance(q, basestring) else f(q)
          for q in s]
```

(Use `str` instead of `basestring` in Python3.)

Example:

```
f([['abcdD', 'asdfaD'], ['qerqD', 'asdfafdasD']])
```

returns:

```
[['abcd', 'asdfa'], ['qerq', 'asdfafdas']]
```

Comment: This is nice, but `basestring` is a python2 thing. You could add a py3 version instead.

Comment: Right.  To have it both ways:  `q.strip('D') if 'strip' in dir(q) else f(q)`.

Comment: Yep, I use python3

Comment: Waiting for an `except` operator ;-)  `return [q.strip('D') except f(q)]` if you take my meaning ;-)

Comment: @Alfe While I am also waiting for that, it would not help here. `str.strip` does not raise an exception when it cannot find the character(s) to strip.

Comment: But `list.strip` raises one.

Answer (score 2):

how about a '`map` happy' approach - just for fun, not any advantages I can see

```
list(map(list, map(lambda txt: map(lambda x: x.rstrip('D'), txt), texts)))

Out[240]: [['abcd', 'asdfa'], ['qerq', 'asdfafdas']]
```

Comment: Don't think it is fastest way, but funniest! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
texts = [['abcdD', 'asdfaD'], ['qerqD', 'asdfafdasD']]
new_texts = [[b[:-1] if b.endswith('D') else b for b in i] for i in texts]
```

Output:

```
[['abcd', 'asdfa'], ['qerq', 'asdfafdas']]
```

Comment: What if `D` doesn't exist at the end of the string?

Comment: Preferably `b.strip('D')`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ added the condition to check for that.